# How to add the controller name/path to spring mvc view prefix?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, view, controller

In order to have an ordered path structure for spring views, I try to add the controller name to the view prefix in order to do this:

```
/settedConfigurationViewPrefix/${controllerName or controllerRequestMappingName}/viewPath
```

This allow have this structure in the view path:

```
   -ViewPath
       -Controller1
          -view1
          -view2
       -Controller2
           -view2
```

I try with this solution and it works, but i think that there will be a most elegant form:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("user")
public class UserController {
    private final String PATH="User";

    @RequestMapping(value = {"", "/"})
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView index() {
        String message = "Welcome to the world of spring.";
        return new ModelAndView(PATH+"index", "User", message).addObject("message",message);
    }
```

There is another way to do this more elegant with spring?

Comment: I too use a similar solution. You can do it in more complicated ways. But this method is simple and clear.

Comment: Controllers do not always return subordinate views. In the long run you'll probably get tired of this. I structure Views using a "client" logic, and I structure Controllers using a "server" logic. They're separate structures but with the help of IDEs you quickly "go to" the returned views and viceversa.

Comment: why dont you try this `@RequestMapping(value = "/{type}/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

Comment: @Johna sure! it is a simple way, but I find most automatic way, maybe  using spring annotations or similar